# good idea to modify Python to accept continue statement in interactive mode?

Tags: python, pdb

as an alternative to using **pdb**, I would have a use for the Python `continue` statement in interactive mode, after control-C during a script invocation with `python -i`. that way, say at a `raw_input('continue->')` prompt in my script, I could break out, inspect/modify things, and go right back to the `raw_input` prompt (or whatever code caused an exception) with a `continue` command. the `break` command outside of a loop could also be repurposed for symmetry, but I'd have less use for that. before submitting a PEP for this, I'd like some feedback from the Python community.

it might be possible to do something similar just using a PYTHONSTARTUP script and the `inspect` module, but if so I haven't figured it out yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ctrl-C raised a KeyboardInterrupt exception in your script. Since you didn't catch that exception, the program terminated. Only then the interactive prompt appears.

You can't continue because your program is already over. The fact that you pressed Ctrl-C just raised an exception, the program didn't **pause** at that exact place. It continued execution, up to the last line, and finished.

There's no way to know where you want to continue to. For that you need a real debugger.

Comment: OK, I grok. Thanks. Because my variables and objects were still visible, I was guessing that the execution stack was still hidden somewhere too, but now after testing with inspect and traceback, I have to agree.

Comment: and thanks for sparing me the ignominy of posting an impossible PEP!